# Wordpress Plugin Tool Tip Helpers

Tags: plugin-development, tooltip

Sometimes when I install a new plugin, it gives me "tool tips" or "helper boxes" floating around the screen at strategic places helping the user to understand the plugin better or certain features. When user hits the X button to close these "bubbles" they no longer appear. These seems like an amazing way to help the user when they first use a plugin. My problem is I have no clue what the proper name of these are and how to go about adding them to my plugins. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you find your favorite plugin that exhibits this behavior, contact the author, and ask her?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "pointers", available since 3.3 and you're right it lacks documentation.

It's done with a little bit of JavaScript. You may look at this post to [find useful information about pointers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162794/31376).

It uses native WP scripts and styles this way :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-pointer' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-pointer' );
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328125/1930236) to get inspiration ^^.